# Trying to push a new view after server response in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to show my new view after the success login process with Firebase, my signUp and Recover password are already working because I'm showing it as a sheet but in this one, I want to show a new view, I have tried with NavigationLink, with onReceive but I have been unable to do this work.

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var formOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var presentSignUpSheet = false
    @State private var presentPasswordRecoverySheet = false
    @State private var presentLobbySheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            HeaderView(title: Constants.appName)
            Spacer()

            Divider()

            Group {
                BodyView(value: viewModel).viewSelection(view: Constants.QuestionnaireView.signIn.rawValue)

                LCButton(text: Constants.login) {
                    self.viewModel.signIn()
                }.alert(isPresented: $viewModel.thereIsAnError) {
                    Alert(title: Text(Constants.alert), message: Text(viewModel.errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text(Constants.ok)))
                }

                Button(action: {
                    self.presentSignUpSheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(Constants.signUp)
                }.sheet(isPresented: $presentSignUpSheet) {
                    SignUpView()
                }.padding()

                Button(action: {
                    self.presentPasswordRecoverySheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(Constants.forgotPassword)
                }.sheet(isPresented: $presentPasswordRecoverySheet) {
                    RecoverPasswordView()
                }.padding()
            }


        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .padding()
            .offset(y: self.formOffset)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var user = User()
    @Published var confirmPassword = ""
    @Published var thereIsAnError = false
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    var viewDismissalModePublisher = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    var onSuccessLogin = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()

    private var shouldPopView = false {
        didSet {
            viewDismissalModePublisher.send(shouldPopView)
        }
    }

    private var shouldShowLobbyView = false {
        didSet {
            onSuccessLogin.send(shouldShowLobbyView)
        }
    }

    func registerSuccess() {

        self.user.email = ""
        self.user.password = ""
        self.confirmPassword = ""

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.shouldPopView = true
        }
    }

    func signUpProcess() {
        if user.password != confirmPassword {
            errorMessage = Constants.passConfirmWrong
            thereIsAnError.toggle()
        } else {
            signUp()
        }
    }

    func signUp() {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: user.email, password: user.password) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.errorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                self.thereIsAnError.toggle()
            } else {
                self.registerSuccess()
            }
        }
    }

    func signIn() {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user.email, password: user.password) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.errorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                self.thereIsAnError.toggle()
            } else {
                self.shouldShowLobbyView.toggle()
                self.user.email = ""
                self.user.password = ""
            }
        }
    }

    func recoverPassword() {
        Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: user.email) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.errorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                self.thereIsAnError.toggle()
            }  else {
                self.user.email = ""
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    self.shouldPopView = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution that mimics some navigation

I was going to write the basics here but nothing better then posting the source with explanation.

[ViewRouter Tutorial](https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-bindableobject/)

This consists in a ObservableObject as EnvironmentObject and it allows you to show views in full screen, rather than sheets.

In your case you would have a `LoginView` and in this view you could open sheets for the Signup and Recover Password views and the `LobbyView` opening as fullscreen view, like it would in UIKit with the `present` method